# SDO_GEOMETRY Equivalent in Postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, geometry

I am trying copy an oracle table into postgres. One of the columns in the oracle table is of "**sdo_geometry**" type. I want to know what is the equivalent for that data type in postgresql and how I can copy that data into my postgres table and if it requires any transformation etc. I am not looking for any migration tool as it is just one table and I am manually copying the data which is very small in size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a number of geometrical data types built in, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html). These offer limited functionality, but if these types and the functions and operators available for them do the trick for you, it would be the simplest solution.

If you need more advanced geometry support, you'll have to install the [PostGIS extension](http://postgis.net/).